# Change color and size according to label (matplolib, python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to show a scatter plot using matplotlib and so far showing the data, color and size is good when hardcoded but what I need to assign size and color according to a label set, for example, DataSet looks like:

```
data = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
label =['label1','label3','label3']
```

The scatter plot should looks like this

[image]

About Colors:

```
so label1 is green
so label2 is red
so label3 is blue
```

About size: the difference size between each one is small you can tell the diff.

Any help is appreciated, I am stating to code in python

Thanks

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: @racekiller, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet you can use. This [example from the matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) docs might help if you need more customization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1,2],[2,1],[1,1]]
labels = ['label1','label2','label3']

colorMap = {'label1': 'g',
            'label2': 'r',
            'label3': 'b'}
sizeMap = {'label1': 10,
            'label2': 20,
            'label3': 30}

colors = [ colorMap[label] for label in labels]
sizes = [ sizeMap[label] for label in labels]
x,y = zip(*data)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=colors, s=sizes)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @racekiller Excellent. Then please mark the question closed